# Eslint. Правильная обработка события клика по элементу nav

Tags: reactjs, eslint

В приложении используется react/redux/react-router 4
Есть компонент всплывающего меню, в нем достаточно много элементов, можно ли повесить обработчик клика на тег nav и в нем запустить `action` который скроет меню? Пс меню открывается в другом месте приложения. Вот пример как выглядит render метод компонента menu:

```
return (
  <nav onClick={this.handleClickCloseMenu}>
    <Link
      to="/smth"
      activeClassName="is-active"
    >
      smth
    </Link>
    <Link
      to="/smth2"
      activeClassName="is-active"
    >
      smth2
    </Link>
  </nav>
)
```

Если я вешаю обработчик клика на nav, то линтер ругается на `jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions` end `jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions`. Но я не понимаю какую роль можно поставить в этом случае nav, явно не button. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с этим?

Comment: Оберни просто nav в div или div в nav и туда прокинь обработчик =)

Comment: Это никак не повлияет на ситуацию. Что div, что nav не являются interactive элементами.

Answer (score 0):

Я тут немного подумал и решил завязаться на параметр `key`, его генерит `react-router`. В `componentDidUpdate` смотреть на `key` и если текущий отличается от предыдущего, то скрываем меню. Если оно открыто конечно.
Вариант решения с обработчиком клика оказался неверным.